# Azure Subscription creation using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

We are trying to spin up an azure subscription using terraform. But unable to find any exact code which delivers successful subscription creation. Below is the brief description of the possible scenarios we have tried executing.

1. We used the below code and executed it and the role we had was
   `Account Owner Role` -But the code is successful but we aren't able to
   see the subscription in the portal. Link for the code:

   https://github.com/aztfmod/terraform-azurerm-caf/tree/5.4.8/modules/subscriptions
2. Below is the next code we tested with again `Account Owner role` - But
   the error message is below. Link for the code: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subscription#example-usage---creating-a-new-alias-and-subscription-for-a-microsoft-customer-account

   ```
   Error Message: creating new Subscription (Alias "XXXX7"):
   subscription.AliasClient#Create: Failure sending request:
   StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidSubCreationScope"
   Message="Not a valid subscription creation scope", with
   azurerm_subscription.testtf, on main.tf line 31, in resource
   "azurerm_subscription" "testtf":   31: resouce
   "azurerm_subscription" "testtf" {
   ```
3. Another code we tried executing - But its destroying the older
   subscription. Link for the code is same:
   https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subscription#example-usage---creating-a-new-alias-and-subscription-for-a-microsoft-customer-account

Request any suggestions/help at the earliest for the same so can help us.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: this is well documented https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subscription

Comment: @Liam We have already gone through the same and the above 2 and 3  pointer depicts on that code with error message. Can we sync on the same and try once so that helpful.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: @liam we have used the same link given by you above https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subscription-  " Example Usage - creating a new Alias and Subscription for a Microsoft Customer Account"  Below is the message :creating new Subscription (Alias "XXXX7"): subscription.AliasClient#Create: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidSubCreationScope" Message="Not a valid subscription creation scope".

Comment: Can you please provide the terraform code you are using and the versions of the terraform azure rm provider and terraform version as well ..

Comment: in the second point the error is because you are using a wrong billing scope for creating the subscription . What is your billing type i.e. EA/MCA/MPA ?

Comment: for 3rd one it destroys because you are replacing the  script which you had used earlier with a new one and same is also mentioned in the bracket after detroyed

Comment: @ansumanBal-Mt 
1. Terraform version and rm provided is good and updated as we are doing in AZ CLI in portal.
2. Its EA portal we are trying.
3. Yes not sure
But we have successful done it its because we didnt mention- Billing portal no we were placing the name.Hence it wasnt.Thank to all those helped.

Comment: @ansumanBal-Mt as requested solution that was applied is shared above and edited in the last part of the question with what has been changed and screenshot .it will help future on this community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Error Message: creating new Subscription (Alias "XXXX7"): subscription.AliasClient#Create: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0
-- Original Error: Code="InvalidSubCreationScope" Message="Not a valid subscription creation scope", with azurerm_subscription.testtf, on main.tf line 31, in resource "azurerm_subscription" "testtf":   31: resouce "azurerm_subscription" "testtf" {
```

As I have mentioned in comments , ***The above issue was with the billing scope which was being used for creating the subscription . Instead of `Name` you should use `Billing account No.` and `Enrollment no.` in the `billing_account_name` & `enrollment_account_name` Arguments like below*** :

```
data "azurerm_billing_enrollment_account_scope" "example" {
  billing_account_name    = "1234567890"
  enrollment_account_name = "0123456"
}

resource "azurerm_subscription" "example" {
  subscription_name = "My Example EA Subscription"
  billing_scope_id  = data.azurerm_billing_enrollment_account_scope.example.id
}
```

***Note: Please make sure that you are using all the correct details which are can be found from EA portal.***

Answer (score 0):

i get this recently and the problem was that the identity which is used to call the subscription creation in Terraform does not have the subscription creator role of the new api. my spn had the subscription role of the legacy api.
to grant the subscription role to the spn, use this link:

focus on this section: Assign the subscription creator role to the SPN

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/assign-roles-azure-service-principals

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/2019-10-01-preview/enrollment-account-role-assignments/put?tabs=HTTP